# What is the difference among dealt/get dealt/got dealt?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

What is the difference in the meaning among these following sentences?

> **A**. Priority cases ***get*** ***dealt*** with first.
>
> **B**. Priority cases are ***dealt*** with first.
>
> **C**. Priority cases are ***got*** ***dealt*** with first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples in *passive voice*,

> Priority cases **get dealt** with first.
>   Priority cases **are dealt** with first.

are the *present* and *future* statements of priority

> Priority cases are **got dealt** with first.

is grammatically incorrect, possibly the *past*

> Priority cases **got dealt** with first.

is correct stating how priorities *were* handled.